# How to emit a 64 bit unsigned integer with a PyQt signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, integer-overflow

I ran into integer overflow issues when using `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)` in the past, because it seems that the python int becomes a C int (32 bit signed integer) in the C++ call. This limits the maximum value that the signal can emit to 2,147,483,647.

I worked around this issue by emitting a `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)` instead, but I imagine this adds a lot of overhead to the signal.

Is there a way to specify exactly which flavor of integer I want the signal to emit in my python code?

Comment: Using `object` does not carry any significant overhead, because PyQt will send a pointer rather than converting from a Python type to a C++ type (and back again, if the receiver is a Python slot). Are you *absolutely certain* that this API could never send an integer of unbounded size?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the useful info about pointers. In my case, I am certain that my int will always be a `uint64` (it is an amount of satoshis in a bitcoin transaction).

Comment: The big question, if PyQt is smart enough to use pointers for arbitrary objects, is why does PyQt choose to pass an `int32` when I want it to pass a python `int`?

Comment: PyQt isn't being smart. It does automatic conversions for a few basic types, but otherwise just refuses to guess. The reason why `int` is always cast to a 32-bit value is largely historical. Earlier versions of PyQt required the use of the C++ `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, so the design decision was partly influenced by ease of porting and/or backwards compatibility. But more to the point, this all happened before [PEP 237](https://peps.python.org/pep-0237/), so Python would still have had both `int` and `long` at the time.

Comment: So: in the past, you could have used `long`, but now you must either use `object` (as per [the PyQt docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqt-pyobject-signal-argument-type)), or perhaps `"quint64"` (which is guaranteed to be the same size on all platforms).

Answer (score 1):

When working with PyQt and dealing with signal-slot mechanisms, especially with large integers, the issue you're encountering is indeed due to the fact that Python's `int` gets converted to a C++ `int` when using `pyqtSignal(int)`. This conversion limits the integer size due to the 32-bit signed integer limit in C++.

Using `pyqtSignal(object)` is a workaround, as it allows Python objects (which includes Python's unlimited size `int`) to be transmitted via the signal. However, as you correctly noted, this could add overhead due to the dynamic nature of Python objects.

To specify the exact type of integer, you can use `QtCore.pyqtSignal` with specific C++ integer types that PyQt provides. These types include `quint32`, `qint64`, and `quint64` for 32-bit and 64-bit integers, both signed and unsigned. Here's how you can use them:

1. **For a 64-bit Signed Integer:**
   Use `QtCore.pyqtSignal('qint64')` to create a signal that can handle 64-bit signed integers. This increases the limit to ±9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

   ```py
   from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

   class MyEmitter(QObject):
       mySignal = pyqtSignal('qint64')

       def emit_signal(self, value):
           self.mySignal.emit(value)
   ```
2. **For a 64-bit Unsigned Integer:**
   Use `QtCore.pyqtSignal('quint64')` if you need an unsigned 64-bit integer, which allows values up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

   ```py
   mySignal = pyqtSignal('quint64')
   ```

By specifying the signal with these types, you can avoid the overhead of using `object` and still have a larger range of integer values than the default 32-bit range. It's also more precise in terms of the data types being passed around, which is generally good practice in both Python and Qt development.

Remember to handle these signals appropriately in the slots connected to them, ensuring the slot functions are compatible with the data type of the signal.

Comment: This answer is precisely backwards. If `object` is used, there is almost no overhead at all, because PyQt will simply pass a pointer. This means the argument that is sent will be *exactly* what is received (i.e. it will satisfy an `is` test). By contrast, using a C++ type carries much more overhead, since the argument must be converted from a Python type to a C++ type and (possibly back again) every time the signal is fired. There's often very little point in doing this unless the receiver actually *requires* a specific type - which is very rarely the case for most Python slots.

Comment: Of course, there are some circumstances when sending a pointer may be undesirable - for example, there may be thread-safety considerations when emitting a cross-thread signal. But more generally speaking, it's a mistake to think in terms of some mythical "best practice" in cases like this. There's often much more important *practical* concerns that need to taken into account when marshalling arguments between Python and C++. Imposing type-restrictions without any practical justification at all is usually unpythonic, and may even lead to subtle bugs.